# Copy check state of a set of checkboxes to another fieldset

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm working on project where I have **fieldset #a** like this.

```
<fieldset id="a">
      <input type="checkbox" name="c1" value="v1" checked="checked" />
      <input type="checkbox" name="c2" value="v2"/>
      <input type="checkbox" name="c3" value="v3"/>
</fieldset>
```

This **fieldset #a** *checkbox : is checked* value is Dynamic.

I have another **fieldset #b** on the same page.

What I want is to Assign/Copy *checkbox : is checked* value from **fieldset #a to fieldset #b**  *Serially* on page load. *[ Both fieldset have equal number of checkboxes. ]*

```
<fieldset id="b">
      <input type="checkbox" name="cc1" value="vv1"/>
      <input type="checkbox" name="cc2" value="vv2"/>
      <input type="checkbox" name="cc3" value="vv3"/>
</fieldset>
```

How can I achieve this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it using that selector you mentioned and then looping each of the values, getting their index, and updating the next fieldsets checkboxes according to those indicies.

Like this:

```
$('fieldset#a input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){   
    $('fieldset#b input[type="checkbox"]').eq($(this).index()).prop('checked',true);
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/hHnLu/

Comment: @MANnDAaR I just made a small edit on it a moment ago, use that instead.

Comment: If some checkboxes was checked in fieldset #b then your code would fail. Let's check mine: http://jsfiddle.net/nPnMa/ and yours: http://jsfiddle.net/NVPN6/

Comment: @CoolEsh Yes, my answer doesn't take into account what the values are on the second fieldset are, as that wasn't part of the requirement. The easiest solution would be to just uncheck all checkboxes in my example with: `$('fieldset#b input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',false)` before copying, like here http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/NVPN6/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
$( '#b' ).children( 'input:checkbox' ).each( function( i ) {
    var aChecked = $( '#a' ).children( 'input:checkbox' ).eq( i ).prop( 'checked' );
    if ( aChecked )
    {
        $( this ).prop( 'checked', true );
    }
    else
    {
        $( this ).removeProp( 'checked' );
    }
} );
```

Comment: I just noticed above that @Niklas code works perfectly if you don't care about which checkboxes WAS checked before the script execution in fieldset #b.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get above stuff working hence I tried below approach and it worked.

```
// lets uncheck all the checkboxes in first fieldset                                                                                             
$('#b input[type=checkbox]').removeProp('checked');                                    

  cj('#b [type=checkbox]').each(function() {
     if (cj(this).prop('checked') ) {
         // here get the index of current element 
         // then modify below code to set prop checked
         cj('#a [type=checkbox]').prop('checked',true);
     }
});
```

Hope this helps!!!