# Copy Selected Checkbox Value From One Checkbox To Another Immediately Using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, django-forms, django-templates

I'm relatively new to Jquery and have been struggling with this problem for the last day or so.  I am trying to do something seemingly simple, but I can't quite work it out.  I have two identical checkboxes with many entries and multiple choices can be selected by the end user in either checkbox.  If a value in checkboxa is selected, I want it to immediately select the identical value in the checkboxb.  I have researched many solutions, and I have tried the following:

```
       $(document).ready(function (){
       $("#id_checkboxa").change(function() {
         $('#id_checkboxa input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
             $('#id_checkboxb input[type="checkbox"]').eq($(this).index()).prop('checked',true);
         });
       });
      });
```

My HTML.  I'm using Django template and forms with a queryset for the choices, which is why I am trying to leverage the ID via Jquery for checkbox manipulation.

```
<div class="spacer34">
  <label class="title130">Checkboxa:</label>
    <div class="spacer68">
      <div class="spacer73">
        {{ form.checkboxa }}
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I found the approach above by referencing the following code snippet on SO..[Copy check state of a set of checkboxes to another fieldset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439900/copy-check-state-of-a-set-of-checkboxes-to-another-fieldset)

The above will copy the first value I select in checkboxa to the top of the checkboxb, but that's it.  I suspect I need to loop through the index or create an array to try and find the checked values, but can't quite work it out.  I definitely want to use the JQUERY ID approach in solving this problem.  Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

After experimenting, I have gotten as far as...

```
            $(document).ready(function (){
            $("#id_checkboxa").change(function() {
                console.log("Hello world!");            
             });
             });
```

And my console will show the hello world!

When I try to do something like...

```
            $(document).ready(function (){
            $("#id_checkboxa").change(function() {
                console.log("Hello world!");
                let selectedValA = $(this).val();
                let isAChecked = $(this).prop("checked");
                $(`#id_checkboxb[value=${selectedValA}]`).prop("checked", isAChecked);
             });
             });
```

I get the following error:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #id_checkboxb[value=]
    at Function.fb.error (jquery.min.js:2)
    at fb.tokenize (jquery.min.js:2)
    at fb.select (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.fb [as find] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:2)
    at new n.fn.init (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLUListElement.<anonymous> ((index):85)
    at HTMLUListElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLUListElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

I know from prior experimentation that Django forms and JQuery can be a challenge to connect just right at times.  Thanks in advance for any other thoughts.

If I do the following...

```
              $(document).ready(function (){
              $("#id_checkboxa").change(function() {
                  console.log("Hello world!");
                  let selectedValA = $(this).val();
                  let isAChecked = $(this).prop("checked");
                    $('#id_checkboxb input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
               });
               });
```

The minute I select a checkbox value in checkboxa, all of checkboxb values get selected.  I am trying to just get the value I selected in checkboxa to appear n checkboxb, not all checkboxes.

Comment: Hey Steve, can you give an idea what your HTML looks like? I am having trouble imagining what "two identical checkboxes with many entries and multiple choices can be selected by the end user in either checkbox" looks like.

Comment: @Andrew Lohr.  Thanks for the response.  I am using django forms and templates.  I have updated my code above to include the HTML that essentially represents the checkboxes.  I have successfully done something similar using the Jquery ID to get the elements since Django templates don't easily allow for straightforward HTML in this case as it relates to checkboxes.

Comment: @Andrew Lohr and DreamTek.  Thank you for your input.  I've played around with this all morning, but can't quite get it to work.  Since I'm using Django forms, it's a bit trickier I suspect.  I actually love the simplicity of Django forms, but sometimes finding documentation or examples of some of the seemingly simplest of things can be very frustrating.  I know from fooling around with Jquery and my Django forms that it is very particular about using the ID for certain operations.  I've updated my code to show how far I can get.

Comment: Steve, it could be the string template tripping you up. Maybe your env doesn't allow for ES6 (newer javascript) functions like string templates. You can replace it with this line and see if it works `$("#id_checkboxb[value=" + selectedValA + "]")`

Comment: @Andrew Lohr.  Thanks again.  I tried your suggestion and it still doesn't work.  I uipdated the code entries at the top to show that I can kind of get it to work...but not quite the way I was hoping.  If I include input[type=checkbox], I seem to make further progress, but I am trying to just get the selected values, not all of the values.

Comment: @Andrew Lohr.  Is it maybe a syntax issue with value?  I've been playing with it and it seems like my editor doesn't like the original syntax of the value parameter in this line...               $(`#id_checkboxb[value=${selectedValA}]`).prop("checked", isAChecked);

Comment: Its not a real syntax issue, maybe your IDE isn't configured for ES6 style syntax. Your last posted attempt looks close, try using classes like I do in my example below. If you have multiple elements with the same ID you are using ID's incorrectly. ID's are supposed to be unique, classes do not need to be unique

Comment: @Andrew Lohr.  Thank you for your help today.  I changed it to classes as you suggested and got the following error message...syntax error, unrecognized expression: .spacer73[value=].  Whether I use ID or class, I get this error.  Not sure why.  Obviously your code works fine.  Perhaps my JQuery library is the wrong one?  I'm new to Jquery but am using this CDN.            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  Should I be using some other library?

Comment: Added quotes to fix error.  No longer get error when I had quotes in right place but still no output.                       $(`.spacer83[value="${selectedValA}"]`).prop("checked", isAChecked);  Also dumped data to console and appears variable selectedValA is not being gotten.  Blank output.

Comment: I'm using a Django modelmultiplechoicefield, checkboxselect multiple as my form.  Could this be part of the reason that this is not working?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Django, so I am not sure if that is a problem, but I doubt it. have you tried `$(".spacer83[value=" + selectedValA + "]").prop("checked", isAChecked); ` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180942/discussion-between-steve-smith-and-andrew-lohr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I know what you are trying to do. This seems like it could be easier with classes (group the checkboxes by class names)

When a checkbox with `checkboxA` class is clicked it will also check the checkbox with class `checkboxB` and only if it also has the same value as checkboxA

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".checkboxA").change(function() {
    let selectedValA = $(this).val();
    let isAChecked = $(this).prop("checked");
    // get a checkbox from the checkboxs with class "checkboxB" and have the same value as the checked checkboxA and set its checked prop to the same as checkboxA
    $(`.checkboxB[value=${selectedValA}]`).prop("checked", isAChecked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- checkbox set A -->
<div>
one <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxA" value="1"/>
two <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxA" value="2"/>
three <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxA" value="3"/>
four <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxA" value="4"/>
five <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxA" value="5"/>
</div>

<br/>
<br/>

<!-- checkbox set B -->
<div>
one <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxB" value="1"/>
two <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxB" value="2"/>
three <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxB" value="3"/>
four <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxB" value="4"/>
five <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxB" value="5"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you simply toggle all boxes of same class that are not the selected checkbox?

```js
$('.CbAB').off('change').on('change', function() {
  $('.CbAB').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="CbAB" type="checkbox" name="CB" value="A">A<br>
<input class="CbAB" type="checkbox" name="CB" value="B">B<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using Django forms and templates, I could not easily use class.  Leveraging the suggestions above along with a ton of research.  I found that I needed to use the input name and not the class or ID.  Here is my code that solved my problem.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $("[name=checkboxa]").change(function() {
            let selectedValA = $(this).val();
            let isAChecked = $(this).prop("checked");
            $(`[name=checkboxb][value="${selectedValA}"]`).prop("checked", isAChecked);
          });
        });
        });
```

You need to interrogate your DOM and figure out what the name of the checkboxes is. In the case above, the name was checkboxa and checkboxb.  Thanks for all of the suggestions that helped get me here.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked in for me:

```
$('#id_checkboxa').attr("checked", $('#id_checkboxb').prop("checked"));
```

`attr` returns the attribute value: the value of the FIRST matched element.

The `attr()` method should be used for retrieving HTML attributes.

The `prop()` method sets or returns the properties and values of the selected elements.