# Django Modelmultiplechoicefield Checkboxselectmultiple Problem Getting Selected Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have been working all day to try and get the selected values on one set of checkboxes on my Django form and copy the selected ones only to an identical checkbox on my form.  If a user clicks on a checkbox in form.author defined below, I want the same identical checkbox to automatically be checked on form.favorite_author defined below.

I've tried a JQuery approach as documented here...[Copy Selected Checkbox Value From One Checkbox To Another Immediately Using JQUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52539570/copy-selected-checkbox-value-from-one-checkbox-to-another-immediately-using-jque?noredirect=1#comment92028613_52539570) but no luck so far.  I've recently begun exploring an avenue with the Modelmultiplechoicefield and the checkboxselectmultiple parameters within the form itself.  From what I can tell, when I am using JQuery and trying to check a box on the form, the value is coming back as undefined which is most likely why it is not propagating the checkbox selection to the other checkbox.

Here is my form....

class ManagerUpdateNewAssociateForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = Library

    self.fields['author'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                            widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
                            queryset=Books.objects.all()

    self.fields['favorite_author'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                            widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
                            queryset=Books.objects.all()
```

My HTML...

```
      <div class="spacer83">
        {{ form.author }}
      </div>

      <div class="spacer83">
        {{ form.favorite_author }}
      </div>
```

When I tried to trace JQuery, it told me the checkbox selections are undefined. I did read a bit about how Modelmultiplechoicefield, since it uses a queryset it doesn't show the selections, but I can't figure out how to get it to.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In combination with the other issue included in this one, I went back to the JQuery route and explored further.  From what I can tell, I was not able to use the class for the input because of the way the HTML for Django forms is generated in this use case.  I ultimately was able to leverage the input name and then used the code below to interrogate the checkboxes accordingly:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $("[name=author]").change(function() {
            let selectedValA = $(this).val();
            let isAChecked = $(this).prop("checked");
            $(`[name=favorite_author][value="${selectedValA}"]`).prop("checked", isAChecked);
          });
        });
        });
```